# correct way to use "tel:" for australia numbers

Tags: html, mobile, href

this is more of a 'straya question. I want to have a number on a website clickable on mobile. But I'm not sure what syntax to use. Example I have so far:

```
<a href="tel:+0744444444">07 4444 4444</a>
```

Is the area code (07) necessary? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Whatever you enter there is what the phone will dial..

Comment: I came here looking for a way to do 1300, 13, and 1800 numbers. Apparently the [only](http://www.netmagellan.com/coding-australian-13-and-1300-tel-numbers-404-errors-1916.html) [way](https://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/2481403) to do it (that works locally and internationally) is to [suffix](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3966#section-6) the `href` with `;phone-context=+61`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 07 code is necessary if you are not calling from within the 07 area.  There might be another number 4444 4444 elsewhere in Australia but not within 07.

You are probably best to use the international code for Australia +61 and then drop the 0.  So the number would be +61744444444.  That will work from anywhere.

Comment: You bloody beauty mate. I knew +61 applied to mobile numbers, but wasn't too sure about landline numbers. Many thanks to you